# Can I use "let ... alone" to mean "even though/if"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, poetry

I am composing a poem and have something like this

> Even if/though it is thousand miles far, we can still share the one.

in mind, which I want to express it more poetically as

> Let thousand miles alone,
>   Can we still share the one.

It kinda makes sense to me.  But I am not sure whether it also makes the same sense to others.  Is this use of the phrase *let alone* correct?

Note that I am aware of [two](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29878/the-phrase-let-alone) [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124358/not-to-mention-let-alone-much-less-still-less) regarding the phrase *let alone* here, but neither of them addresses my issue.

Comment: I feel "let alone" should not be split.

Comment: No. *Let alone* does not mean what you intend here as *even though*, you cannot use the expression. Google usage examples of the two expression to understand the difference.

Comment: If you need further help, try asking on [ell.se]

Comment: @mplungjan: It can, as in "let me alone" and "let the dog alone".

Comment: But not in "let alone" in your version which I assume is "let alone someone or something - not to mention" like "I will not consider a thousand miles, let alone one"

Comment: Poetry puts you in control; you can break up pairs of words at will. However, it will not always result in a good poem. *Leave me alone* can be said as *let me alone* (though it is quaint), but **let alone** means something different, and should be regarded as joined at the hip.

Comment: @Kris - I've seen much more basic questions on EL&U that were not sent to ELL but should have been. I think this is a good Q for us, and Susan gave a good A.

Comment: @martinf That "A" does not even touch upon *though*. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Let alone** someone or something means something very different than **let someone or something alone** (also stated more commonly as **leave**  *something alone*).

[**Let alone**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20alone) means to say nothing of/not to mention, and is used especially to emphasize the improbability of a contrasting example (the *someone or something* in the above example). *let alone* is used as an inseparable pair.

> I can't remember the title of the book we were supposed to read, **let alone** the details of the story.
>   We haven't got the money to stay in a seedy motel, **let alone** a stay at the Ritz.

Synonyms for *let alone* are also word-pairs (or more): much less, never mind, still less, not to mention. These should also be kept together.

[**Let (x) alone**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+alone) means to avoid touching, bothering, or communicating with someone or something (such as interrupting).

> Now therefore **let me alone**, that my wrath may burn hot against them and I may consume them, in order that I may make a great nation of you.
>   If those gentlemen would **let me alone** I should be much obliged to them.

If you get the impression that *let (someone) alone* is a more formal usage, it's because it's been replaced in more modern language by *leave (x) alone*.